# How many strings of four decimal digits do not contain the same digit twice?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to check whether my concept and answer is right

I am considering strings of four decimal digits that contain the same digit twice.  With this, 
I have the possibilities of $xxyz,xyxz,yxxz,yxzx,yzxx,xyzx$ where $x$ is the same digit, and $y, z$ are randomly different decimal digits taken.
 So $10 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 = 720$ and $6$ possibilities, then $720 \cdot 6 = 4320$ ways. 
 Now consider digits that have pattern $xxyy, yyxx,xyxy,yxxy,yxyx,xyyx$, here $10 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 9=810 \cdot 6= 4860$ ways. 
Then total combinations are $10^4 =10000$ then $10000-4320-4860=820$ ways .

Comment: Why not calculate the probability that no number is repeated?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I suspect it concerns the number of strings that do not contain the same digit *exactly* $2$ times.

Comment: Oh, the wording confused me. Pardon

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Do you mean how many strings of four decimal digits do not contain the same digit twice or exactly twice?

Comment: This is the question of Kenneth Rosen discrete mathematics textbook, It is mentioned there like this only, You can refer it , Chapter 6 Basics of Counting Exercise 6.1 Question number 26.

Comment: Then the comment of @MohammadZuhairKhan might be useful after all.

Comment: I suspect the intended question was meant to be interpreted as how many strings of four decimal digits contain distinct digits?

Comment: I suspect the same as @N.F.Taussig now. My first suspection was based on how you approached the question, and not so much on the formulation in the title.

Comment: How do you get $yzxxx$ if it is only $4$ decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

Your title is ambiguous (see the comment of Mohammad) and I preassume that it concerns the number of strings that have the property that no digit appears exactly $2$ times.

Where it concerns strings that have $3$ distinct digits your calculation with outcome $$\binom42\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8=4320$$ is correct.

Where it concerns strings that have $2$ distinct digits that both appear twice the outcome should be: $$\frac12\binom42\cdot10\cdot9=270$$
You (maybe accidently) have $2$ factors $9$ instead of $1$ and did not repair double counting.

You could also reason that there are not $6$ but $3$ patterns there ($xxyy$,$xyxy$ and $xyyx$) and this with $10$ choices for $x$ and $9$ remaining choices for $y$.

Comment: Thanks here, I understood the fact.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I want to know , what will be the answer in this case ,when we are assuming same digit exactly twice.